# The variable this.state.plans is undefined after updating

Tags: reactjs

For the life of me I cannot figure out why the variable is not being populated correctly when doing an async request:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import httpService from '../../httpService';

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      plans: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchPlans();
  }

  async fetchPlans() {
    try {
      await httpService.get('/plans')
        .then((response) => {
          const {
            plans,
          } = response.data;

          this.setState({
            plans,
          });

          // Show the correct data in console
          console.log(response.data);
        });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { plans } = this.state;

    // Show as "undefined" in console
    console.log(plans);

    return (
      <div>
        { plans }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Landing);
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the console data as requested in the comments:

[image]

UPDATE

When change `const { paymentPlans } = response.data;` to `const plans = response.data;` I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {plan, planName, price, months, description}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Comment: please show `console.log(response.data);`

Comment: @Cudos because you add image instead of text logs. The idea is to make all content searchable. Using image in your post does not help.

Comment: @WeezHard: The downvote was before the image.

Comment: @Cudos check my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I got, `response.data` is already returning a list of plans.

So, instead of:

```
const { plans } = response.data;
```

Just do:

```
const plans = response.data
```

Or:

```
 setState({
     plans: response.data
 })
```

and then remove the previous line.

---

UPDATE:

for the second update, its happening because of this:

```
  <div>
    { plans }
  </div>
```

Try:

```
<div>
    { plans.planName }
</div>
```